# How does the Scala compiler resolve an implicit conversion

Tags: scala

Yesterday I hit a problem with an implicit conversion. Putting this into import scope:

`object FooConversions {
  implicit def toString(foo: Foo): String = foo.toString
}`

gave me compile errors. Took a while to figure out that calling the function `toString` was the culprit. I didn't spend to much time investigating further but my guess is that it is clashing with the toString method in Object? How does the compiler handle an implicit conversion like this?

```
scala> case class Foo(name: String)
defined class Foo

scala> object FooConversions {
     |   implicit def toString(foo: Foo): String = foo.toString
     | }

defined object FooConversions

scala> import FooConversions._
import FooConversions._

scala> val x: String = Foo("bob")
<console>:16: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Foo
 required: String
       val x: String = Foo("bob")
```

Comment: This question has a good answer on where scala looks for implicits http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits

Comment: You can ofcourse fix this by giving the method in `FooConversions` another name, for example `fooToString`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens due to member shadowing. The imported `toString` is not available in the scope where you expect the implicit conversion to happen. Let's see how it works...

First let's check that implicit works:

```
scala> object FooConversions {
     |   implicit def toString(foo: Foo): String = foo.toString
     |
     |   val x: String = Foo("bob")
     | }
defined object FooConversions
```

Yes it does in the original/definition scope.

Now let's try to see if the imported method `toString` is available:

```
object FooConversions {
  implicit def toString(foo: Foo): String = foo.toString
}

import FooConversions._

val y: String = toString(Foo("bob"))
<console>:28: error: too many arguments for method toString: ()String
       val y: String = toString(Foo("bob"))
```

It's not available - it's being shadowed by the `toString` of the enclosing object. In REPL for the code to compile Scala puts everything in some magic object. In real life code will reside in some object/class.

Trying to call `toString` explicitly to check if it could potentially work:

```
scala> val y: String = FooConversions.toString(Foo("bob"))
y: String = Foo(bob)
```

No problem here obviously.

So the solution is either (1) to rename `toString` to some other name that can't be potentially shadowed:

```
scala> import scala.language.implicitConversions
import scala.language.implicitConversions

scala> case class Foo(name: String)
defined class Foo

scala> object FooConversions {
     |   implicit def toStr(foo: Foo): String = foo.toString
     | }
defined object FooConversions

scala> import FooConversions._
import FooConversions._

scala> val x: String = Foo("bob")
x: String = Foo(bob)
```

or (2) to redefine an implicit (sucks):

```
scala> import scala.language.implicitConversions
import scala.language.implicitConversions

scala> case class Foo(name: String)
defined class Foo

scala> object FooConversions {
     |   implicit def toString(foo: Foo): String = foo.toString
     | }
defined object FooConversions

scala> implicit def toStr(foo: Foo) = FooConversions.toString(foo)
toStr: (foo: Foo)String

scala> val x: String = Foo("bob")
x: String = Foo(bob)
```

p.s. This is not an issue of implicit lookup or implicit scope, but an issue of shadowing/hiding of imported members.

Comment: Great answer, do you know why it is shadowed? The original `toString()` method doesn't take any parameters, so shouldn't this count as overloading?

Comment: Glad I could help. Overloading happens when you define a member either via `def` or via inheritance and in that case there would be no conflict as in `object FooConversions { implicit def toString }` - has 2 `toString` methods. When we import members we reference them from outer scope, and inner scope always "wins" by hiding the outer scope names. I think Scala first does the name resolution removing our `toString` and only then resolves implicits thus not being able to find that implicit conversion.